# Global.asax vs Owin MiddleWare: Setting Thread Culture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin, global-asax, .net-4.6

I have a hybrid asp.net solution with both Webforms and WebAPI 2 (hosted trough owin). I need to make sure that all requests are handled in the correct Culture. Before introducing WebAPI, we had the following code in our `Global.asax` file:

```
public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = GetCulture();
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
}
```

We now introduced WebAPI and it doesn't use the culture set in `Global.asax`. After debugging, we found out that, Since we use `app.UseCookieAuthentication()`, the owin pipeline is executed before `AuthenticateRequest` (so before we set our culture).

So we moved the setting of the culture to an Owin MiddelWare

```
public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext next)
{
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = GetCulture();
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
}
```

This works perfectly for our WebAPI calls, but now our regular Webforms request do not pick up the culture set in the MiddleWare (even though the MiddleWare is executed).

Can someone explain why the culture in de Webforms lifecycle reverts to the default, after is was set in the Owin MiddleWare?

Things I investigated:

- The ManagedThreadIds are the same in the middleware and in global.asax